# TestDisk help to recover mistake

Tags: ubuntu, testdisk

In my rush to create a new USB installation media I selected the wrong USB disk and blatted my ext4 formatted USB disk with all my data on it.  Am hoping to be able to recover the partitions but it keeps detecting “NONE” as the partition table.

[image: NONE]

I can then analyse and find a load of ext4 info but cannot write anything due to “NONE” being selected.

If I select “Intel” it only finds the newly created FAT partition and the files on that.

Am not really sure what I am doing here not how to navigate out of it.  I have a feeling I still have some of the blocks from ext4 so should be able to recover?  But am struggling to understand how to do it.  If anyone has any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you have a partition table on the target disk?

Comment: It did have an ext4 but is now masquerading as a bootable USB as what was there was overwritten by Ubuntu’s “Startup disk creator”

Comment: No, that's a filesystem. Did you have a partition table?

Comment: hmm had not appreciated the difference I had assumed as it had a filesystem it must have had a partition table to assign the filesystem to.  But perhaps not

Comment: If you mounted the disk from `/dev/sdXN`, e.g., `/dev/sda1` in the past, there was a partition table, if the device was mounted directly from `/dev/sdX`, e.g., `/dev/sda`, then you likely didn't have a partition table.  If you did have a partition table, you might be able to try the method outlined [here](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition/recovering.html).

Comment: so looking at syslog from the time I broke the USB I believe it would have had a partition table on it:   
Jul 15 22:39:35 laptop com.ubuntu.USBCreator[7885]: DEBUG:root:Using target: /dev/sdb
Jul 15 22:39:35 laptop com.ubuntu.USBCreator[7885]: DEBUG:root:Unmounting /dev/sdb1

Comment: "_Unmounting /dev/sdb1_" - yes that's indicative of a partition table. Given the small size of the device in question it's probably PC/MBR but it could have been GPT. You could _probably_ re-create an MBR partition table (single ext4 partition spanning the entire disk).